# For which $a \in \mathbb{R}$ are $\sin^2(ax), \cos^2(x)$ and $1$ linear independent.

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to find all $a \in \mathbb{R}$, such that $\sin^2(ax), \cos^2(x),1$ are linear indepent, and for which $a$ they are linear dependent. When $a=1,-1$ it is surely linear dependent, because of the identity: $\sin^2(x)+cos^2(x) = 1$. Now my question is, how to go from here.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by independent, is it *linearly independent*?

Comment: When $a=0$ they are dependent too. :-)

Comment: Changed, it was linear independence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $\sin^2(x) = (1 - \cos(2x))/2$ and
$\cos^2(ax) = (1 + \cos(2ax)/2$.
Hence the span of the three functions is the same as the span of 
$1$, $\cos(2ax)$, and $\cos(2x)$.

Can you see the rest?

Comment: So eventually, we get $a=-1+n\pi$, $a=n\pi$ of $a=1+n\pi$ with $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ for dependence right?

Answer (score 0):

You can employ the [Wronskian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian) to show the linearly independence of functions. Some examples of this method is given [>>here<<](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Wronskian.aspx).